# Не могу создать базу данных из assets в room database android studio

Tags: java, база-данных, android-studio, android-room, room

Не могу загрузить готовую базу данных из assets в room database.

Вроде сделал все как в документации, но приложение не подгружает мою, а создает новую пустую, что делать.

Вот код где создается база данных:

```
package com.gorchatov.shazamclone;

import android.app.Application;
import androidx.room.Room;
public class App extends Application {
private static App instance;

private MusicDatabase musicDatabase;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    instance = this;
    musicDatabase = Room.databaseBuilder(this, MusicDatabase.class, "myfin")
            .allowMainThreadQueries()
            .createFromAsset("myfin.db")
            .build();//сюда надо путь к готовой БД
}

public static App getInstance() {
    return instance;

}

public MusicDatabase getDatabase() {
    return musicDatabase;
}
}
```

Вот лог:

```
2023-05-13 17:45:57.410 15606-15606 ziparchive              com.gorchatov.shazamclone            W  Unable to open '/data/app/~~Yy1PyWTUd-J09JdJQ8BJ6Q==/com.gorchatov.shazamclone-9Hzl1PRbWBZ6gpOCszQ7Ig==/base.dm': No such file or directory
2023-05-13 17:45:57.410 15606-15606 ziparchive              com.gorchatov.shazamclone            W  Unable to open '/data/app/~~Yy1PyWTUd-J09JdJQ8BJ6Q==/com.gorchatov.shazamclone-9Hzl1PRbWBZ6gpOCszQ7Ig==/base.dm': No such file or directory
2023-05-13 17:45:57.686 15606-15606 nativeloader            com.gorchatov.shazamclone            D  Configuring classloader-namespace for other apk /data/app/~~Yy1PyWTUd-J09JdJQ8BJ6Q==/com.gorchatov.shazamclone-9Hzl1PRbWBZ6gpOCszQ7Ig==/base.apk. target_sdk_version=33, uses_libraries=, library_path=/data/app/~~Yy1PyWTUd-J09JdJQ8BJ6Q==/com.gorchatov.shazamclone-9Hzl1PRbWBZ6gpOCszQ7Ig==/lib/arm64, permitted_path=/data:/mnt/expand:/data/user/0/com.gorchatov.shazamclone
2023-05-13 17:45:57.691 15606-15606 GraphicsEnvironment     com.gorchatov.shazamclone            V  ANGLE Developer option for 'com.gorchatov.shazamclone' set to: 'default'
2023-05-13 17:45:57.691 15606-15606 GraphicsEnvironment     com.gorchatov.shazamclone            V  ANGLE GameManagerService for com.gorchatov.shazamclone: false
2023-05-13 17:45:57.692 15606-15606 GraphicsEnvironment     com.gorchatov.shazamclone            V  Neither updatable production driver nor prerelease driver is supported.
2023-05-13 17:45:57.700 15606-15606 NetworkSecurityConfig   com.gorchatov.shazamclone            D  No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
2023-05-13 17:45:57.702 15606-15606 NetworkSecurityConfig   com.gorchatov.shazamclone            D  No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
2023-05-13 17:45:57.735 15606-15650 libEGL                  com.gorchatov.shazamclone            D  loaded /vendor/lib64/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
2023-05-13 17:45:57.757 15606-15650 libEGL                  com.gorchatov.shazamclone            D  loaded /vendor/lib64/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
2023-05-13 17:45:57.760 15606-15606 AppCompatDelegate       com.gorchatov.shazamclone            D  Checking for metadata for AppLocalesMetadataHolderService : Service not found
2023-05-13 17:45:57.769 15606-15650 libEGL                  com.gorchatov.shazamclone            D  loaded /vendor/lib64/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
2023-05-13 17:45:57.824 15606-15606 tov.shazamclone         com.gorchatov.shazamclone            W  Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (unsupported, reflection, allowed)
2023-05-13 17:45:57.827 15606-15606 tov.shazamclone         com.gorchatov.shazamclone            W  Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (unsupported, reflection, allowed)
2023-05-13 17:45:57.835 15606-15606 Compatibil...geReporter com.gorchatov.shazamclone            D  Compat change id reported: 210923482; UID 10173; state: ENABLED
2023-05-13 17:45:57.873 15606-15606 System.out              com.gorchatov.shazamclone            I  0==================
2023-05-13 17:45:57.924 15606-15648 HostConnection          com.gorchatov.shazamclone            D  createUnique: call
2023-05-13 17:45:57.925 15606-15648 HostConnection          com.gorchatov.shazamclone            D  HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb400007363ddae50, tid 15648
2023-05-13 17:45:57.940 15606-15648 HostConnection          com.gorchatov.shazamclone            D  HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v2 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v3 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v4 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan ANDROID_EMU_deferred_vulkan_commands ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_null_optional_strings ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_create_resources_with_requirements ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_ignored_handles ANDROID_EMU_has_shared_slots_host_memory_allocator ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_free_memory_sync ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_shader_float16_int8 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_async_queue_submit ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_queue_submit_with_commands ANDROID_EMU_sync_buffer_data ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_async_qsri ANDROID_EMU_read_color_buffer_dma ANDROID_EMU_hwc_multi_configs GL_OES_EGL_image_external_essl3 GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_host_side_tracing ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_3_0 
2023-05-13 17:45:57.954 15606-15648 OpenGLRenderer          com.gorchatov.shazamclone            W  Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
2023-05-13 17:45:57.955 15606-15648 OpenGLRenderer          com.gorchatov.shazamclone            W  Failed to initialize 101010-2 format, error = EGL_SUCCESS
2023-05-13 17:45:57.956 15606-15648 EGL_emulation           com.gorchatov.shazamclone            D  eglCreateContext: 0xb400007363ddb8d0: maj 3 min 0 rcv 3
2023-05-13 17:45:57.958 15606-15648 EGL_emulation           com.gorchatov.shazamclone            D  eglMakeCurrent: 0xb400007363ddb8d0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0x7578b38080) (first time)
2023-05-13 17:45:58.005 15606-15648 Gralloc4                com.gorchatov.shazamclone            I  mapper 4.x is not supported
2023-05-13 17:45:58.006 15606-15648 HostConnection          com.gorchatov.shazamclone            D  createUnique: call
2023-05-13 17:45:58.006 15606-15648 HostConnection          com.gorchatov.shazamclone            D  HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb400007363dd70d0, tid 15648
2023-05-13 17:45:58.007 15606-15648 goldfish-address-space  com.gorchatov.shazamclone            D  allocate: Ask for block of size 0x100
2023-05-13 17:45:58.007 15606-15648 goldfish-address-space  com.gorchatov.shazamclone            D  allocate: ioctl allocate returned offset 0x1e1ff0000 size 0x8000
2023-05-13 17:45:58.011 15606-15648 Gralloc4                com.gorchatov.shazamclone            W  allocator 4.x is not supported
2023-05-13 17:45:58.027 15606-15648 HostConnection          com.gorchatov.shazamclone            D  HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v2 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v3 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v4 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan ANDROID_EMU_deferred_vulkan_commands ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_null_optional_strings ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_create_resources_with_requirements ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_ignored_handles ANDROID_EMU_has_shared_slots_host_memory_allocator ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_free_memory_sync ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_shader_float16_int8 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_async_queue_submit ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_queue_submit_with_commands ANDROID_EMU_sync_buffer_data ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_async_qsri ANDROID_EMU_read_color_buffer_dma ANDROID_EMU_hwc_multi_configs GL_OES_EGL_image_external_essl3 GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_host_side_tracing ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_3_0 
2023-05-13 17:45:58.110 15606-15648 Parcel                  com.gorchatov.shazamclone            W  Expecting binder but got null!
2023-05-13 17:46:25.405 15606-15614 System                  com.gorchatov.shazamclone            W  A resource failed to call close.
```

Вот это я выводил чтобы понять , что в базе 0 записей: `0==================`

Вот дерево с базой данных:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Приведенный код написан достаточно корректно, а покажите фрагмент кода, где вы делаете запрос на получение данных из базы и какой именно sql-запрос выполняете? Добавьте эту информацию непосредственно в ваш [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1519518/edit).

Comment: Спасибо, теперь мне стыдно , в запросе я вызывал Music , а моя таблица называется Musics , может стоит уже пойти дворы мести...